# Printing out huge plot so I can see the results

Tags: r

I am using GGally::pairs to look at 63 columns of numerical data. The function runs fine but the result is a plot where I can't read any of the column names fully or the numbers (correlations etc.). The resolution is fine, it is just that the plot is compressed so that the plots are tiny and cant really be read (and only part of the text is visible). This is because it prints the plot to the plot viewer in Rstudio I suppose. How can I get the plot to be bigger so I can actually see the results

Comment: What happens if you press export  or save it to a file? Copy to clipboard actually has width and height options but maybe there's a better way to visualize the data?

Comment: If library(plotly) supports this type of ggally plot, `p <- ggplot(...)` then `ggplotly(p)` & clicking export (or using `ggsave()` with `.html` extension) outputs zoomable html in a browser tab, might be worth a try.

Comment: Save a high-resolution copy and zoom in/print it really big? This doesn't seem like specifically a coding question—same advice would apply to being able to see detail in any type of image

Comment: Thanks @dbo please post as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @camille but the problem is more that the images get compressed to fill the space rather than a resolution issue. The resolution is fine its just that I the text only shows a few letters and I dont want to reduce the font size- just plot that shows all the images clearly with all the text

Comment: So that's the sort of detail that could go into an example for the question, so folks can see what exactly the problem is instead of just guessing

Comment: Apologies @camille. I have edited to make it clearer. Ill try to post an image too. Thanks for pulling me up on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revising my comment above, instead of `ggsave()` that I'm not sure can work, this might work, but assumes plotly accommodates the geoms in your plot (it does for a good number of ggplot geoms, but not all, eg many of the `library(ggridges)`'s geoms).

```
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

p <- ggplot(your ggplot data/parameters/geoms) #creates ggplot object
p <- ggplotly(p)  #converts p to html, renders in RStudio console
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(p), "filename.html") #saves as a single html file
```